# how to share Data in key value pair within same android application but installed on two different devices in android

Tags: android

I am developing an application related to home automation in android.

Suppose the name of my application is **X** and is installed on two different android Devices(**user1** & **user2**)

I want to share the data(key value pair) of app **X** from **user1** to the same app in **user2**

I dont want to use internet.

can we do it with sharedpreferences or bluetooth??

but data should transfer from app to app.

How to achieve this???

Comment: Yes can use wifi peer to peer connection to communicate two devices in limited area.

Comment: can you tell me how to do this ?? or any link for reference? any code sample

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22899728/3364266 try this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39589868/how-to-broadcast-message-from-group-owner-to-all-or-particular-clients-andro check this link... you can connect multiple devices in same network using this and can also send and receive data from any connected device.

Comment: @samir..thanks for the link..I can send the data with this link..but i want to receive data in same app on other device.how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by sending a JSON object, through Bluetooth. After recieving the value from the other end, you can parse the JSON.

Comment: I cant use JSON that's the main problem.

Comment: JSONObject student1 = new JSONObject();
try {
    student1.put("id", "3");
    student1.put("name", "NAME OF STUDENT");
    student1.put("year", "3rd");
    student1.put("curriculum", "Arts");
    student1.put("birthday", "5/5/1993");

} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Comment: Now you can send the json student1 to your other device, and parese the content